# Why the usage of GPT is important in (Windows 10, Windows 8.1) from security perspective

Tags: windows-10, windows-8.1, uefi, gpt, guid

Guys!

I am currently researching on usage of GUID in modern operating systems and i have found that there are a small number of reserved partitions in GPT such as MSR, ESP and etc. However, i cannot find any other information of the GPT functioning in UEFI system. Is there are any other functions attached to the GPT?

Thank you!

Comment: Windows in UEFI mode requires GPT, that's all.

Comment: This question is vague. What are you asking really?

Comment: UEFI does not require GPT though, that is just a quirk of windows.

Answer (score 2):

GPT doesn't provide security, it overcomes the limitations of MBR and allows more effective use of modern disks.

Two common problems plague MBR disks:

- only 4 "primary" (bootable) partitions.
  *more than 4 partitions are possible, but this requires partitions to be created within an extended partition. This reduces the effective bootable partitions to 3*
- MBR has a 1.7TB partition limit

[GPT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table) removes these limitations and, when combined with UEFI, adds some extra features.  At a minimum it supports larger disks and there is a "boot" partition that can contain multiple operating system bootloaders or system maintenance "programs".